# Check value of fields before running function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I basically want to have a script on the page which shows a map when it finds two fields on the page named "lng" and "lat" which have a value.

This means that if there are the fields on the page with values, then it will try and display a map, but if not, then it will not.

This is the code I have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/xJhmk/3/

```
function mapDisplay() {

    var latval = $('input[id=lat]').val();
    var lngval = $('input[id=lng]').val();

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latval, lngval),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        scrollwheel: false,
        draggable: false
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
}


$(function () {
    mapDisplay();
});
```

I am not very good at jquery at the moment but this is what I tried which didn't work:

```
if (latval !=NULL && lngval != NULL)){
...my code
}
```

Can someone with a little more knowledge help me understand why this approach doesn't work please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if ( !isNaN(latval) && !isNaN(lngval)) {
```

So basically it checks if the 2 inputs are numbers, and only if true will step into the if condition.

Also

```
var latval = $('input[id=lat]').val();
var lngval = $('input[id=lng]').val();
```

can be safely written as

```
var latval = $('#lat').val(),
    lngval = $('#lng').val();
```

You can hook up the `change` event for the inputs that will display the maps

**Code**

```
function mapDisplay() {

    var latval = $('#lat').val(),
        lngval = $('#lng').val();
      if (!isNaN(parseFloat(latval)) && !isNaN(parseFloat(lngval))) {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(latval, lngval),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            scrollwheel: false,
            draggable: false
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
        $('#map_canvas').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $('#map_canvas').addClass('hidden');
    }
}


$(function () {
    $('input').on('change', mapDisplay).trigger('change');
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xJhmk/7/)**

Comment: isNaN return true when the string is Empty and it is also return true went a null is passed ,

Comment: @FLF. oopps... missed that.. Thanks for pointing it out. I have added an extra condition now..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var latval = $('#lat').val();
var lngval = $('#lng').val();

if ($.trim(latval) != '' && $.trim(lngval) != '') {
    // You code
```

- No need to do this `input[id=lat]`, you can directly call it like `$('#lat')`
- Use `$.trim()` to remove the whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.

Answer (score 1):

your code is correct : you just have to add a line in you css in order to view the map:

add

```
display:block; in #map_canvas
```

like this :

```
#map_canvas {
    display:block;
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

moreover you can change its display setting by setting this display property using jquery(depending upon whether variables have values or not.).

**by default textbox returns string value. so for empty textbox you can check :**

```
if(latval=='' && lngval==''){alert('blank');}
else{your code;}
```

Answer (score 1):

the value returned from text box is not a NULL it is just an empty string so you should check whether the value is empty or not

```
if(latval !="" && lngval !=""){
Your code
}
```

and if you want to specific for only numbers , try adding

```
$.isNumeric()

 if($.isNumeric(latval) && $.isNumeric(lngval )){
    Your code
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are prob checking latitude/longtitude, I would also check if they are [numeric](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/).

```
function checkValues() {
    var valueOK = false;
    if($.isNumeric($('#lat').val())) { 
         if($.isNumeric($('#lng').val())) valueOK = true;
    }

    return valueOK;
}

$(function () {
    if(checkValues) {
         mapDisplay();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access variables like

```
var lat = jQuery.trim($('#lat').val());
var lng = jQuery.trim($('#lng).val());
```

And check if the fields were empty

```
if(lat == '' && lng == '') {
    //do code
} else {
   //show the map
   $("#mapId").show();
}
```